# Can't upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 because of /tmp

Tags: upgrade, mount, tmp

```
Cannot run the upgrade
This is usually caused by a system where /tmp is mounted noexec. 
Please remount without noexec and run the upgrade again.
```

I am very much a newbie and have no idea how to 'remount' the `/tmp` file.